# Как анимировать переход div-ов

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Нужно чтобы при следующем нажатии на кнопку был плавный переход от предыдущего элемента новому. Чтобы при вводе других значений, замена происходила с анимацией. Простой transition не работает, так как функция каждый раз создает новый элемент и уже "transition: 1s" не катит. Может как то через setTimeout() или что другое есть.
Подскажите как сделать красивое появление нового элемента?

```js
var create = false; // false - not created || true - created
function foo(){
 var body = document.getElementById('body'),
  w = document.getElementById('w').value,
  h = document.getElementById('h').value,
  r = document.getElementById('r').value,
  div = document.createElement('div'); //create element(div)
 if(create == true){  // div already created
  var field = document.getElementById('field');
  body.removeChild(field);
  body.appendChild(div);
 }
 if(create == false){ // div not created
  if(w == "" && h == ""){  // stop func if w && h = nothing
   return;
  }
  else{ // create div
   body.appendChild(div);
   create = true;
  }
 }
  div.style.height = h + 'px';
  div.style.width = w + 'px';
  div.style.borderRadius = r + 'px';
  div.style.border = '1px solid white';
  div.id = 'field';
}
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #184287;
 transition: 1s;
}
h1{
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 35px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input{
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 outline: none;
 transition: 1s;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body">
 <h1>Show size</h1>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Width" id="w">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Height" id="h">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Radius" id="r">
 <button onclick="foo()">Create</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а зачем все это? зачем новый элемент если надо один превратить в другой?

Comment: А как это можно сделать? Я пробовал менять стиль уже существующего элемента, но на странице это не отображалось

Comment: можно и должно работать

Answer (score 2):

```js
var create = false,
  obj = {
    w: 0,
    h: 0,
    r: 0,
  },

  previousW,
  previousH,
  previousR;

function foo() {
  obj.w = +document.getElementById('width').value;
  obj.h = +document.getElementById('height').value;
  obj.r = +document.getElementById('radius').value;

  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.height = obj.h + 'px';
  div.style.width = obj.w + 'px';
  div.style.borderRadius = obj.r + 'px';
  div.style.border = '1px solid white';
  div.id = 'field';

  if (!create) {
    if (!obj.w && !obj.h && !obj.r) {
      return;
    } else {
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      create = true;

      //Присваиваем, чтобы узнать предыдущие размеры
      previousW = obj.w;
      previousH = obj.h;
      previousR = obj.r;
    }
  } else {
    var timer = setInterval(() => {

      // Сравниваем текущие длину и ширину с введёнными
      if (parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#field')).width) >= obj.w &&
        parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#field')).height) >= obj.h) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        return;
      }

      draw();

    }, 100); //Время в ms
  }
}

function draw() {
  previousW += 1;
  previousH += 1;
  previousR += 1;

  if (parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#field')).width) <= obj.w) {
    document.querySelector('#field').style.width = previousW + 'px';
  }

  if (parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#field')).height) <= obj.h) {
    document.querySelector('#field').style.height = previousH + 'px';
  }

  if (parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#field')).borderRadius) <= obj.r) {
    document.querySelector('#field').style.borderRadius = previousR + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #184287;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button:target div {
  width: 50px;
  transition: width 5s;
}
```

```html
<h1>Show size</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Width" id="width">
<input type="text" placeholder="Height" id="height">
<input type="text" placeholder="Radius" id="radius">
<button onclick="foo()">Create</button>
```

Моё решение неполное: блок может только увеличиваться. Но, я думаю, ничего сложного для вас не составит доработать этот момент. Надеюсь, моё решение натолкнёт вас на мысль :)

Comment: Лучше рассчитывать количество добавляемых пикселей на шаг анимации. Стратегию `+1px` невозможно адекватно кастомизировать.

Answer (score 1):

Обычный transition должен работать:

```js
function foo(){
 var body = document.getElementById('body'),
  w = document.getElementById('w').value,
  h = document.getElementById('h').value,
  r = document.getElementById('r').value,
    div = document.getElementById('field');
  if (!div) {// Ещё не создан, создаём
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'field';
    div.style.border = '1px solid white';
    div.classList.add('animated');
    body.appendChild(div);
  }
  if(w == "" && h == ""){  // stop func if w && h = nothing
    return;
  }
  div.style.height = h + 'px';
  div.style.width = w + 'px';
  div.style.borderRadius = r + 'px';
}
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #184287;
}
h1{
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 35px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input{
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.animated {
  transition: 3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body">
 <h1>Show size</h1>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Width"  id="w">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Height" id="h">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Radius" id="r">
 <button onclick="foo()">Create</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В transition необязательно указывать что конкретно надо анимировать?

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко, да, необязательно.